# How to run a WPF application on an other computer, as administrator

Tags: wpf

I have a C#/WPF application running inside Visual Studio on one computer. How can I run it on an other Windows computer, preferably without installing VisualStudio first? It needs administrator access, so I cannot use ClickOnce.

I know this is a really basic question, but I could not find it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio right click on the project name and select "Open Folder in File Explorer" then enter the bin folder and the debug folder and you will find an exe file.  Run it on the other computer by right clicking this exe and select "run as administrator"

Comment: I do the same, the app is running fine but can't select sql data from main pc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that an application runs with admin right, you should add an application manifest file (On your project : `Add New Item` -> `Application Manifest File`)

Inside this app.manifest, there is a node called `requestedExecutionLevel`. Its value should be changed like this :

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Once it's done and the application is built, you can take the .exe file generated and send it to the other computer. On the application launchup, the UAC should prompt to ask for admin privileges